# Class fields losing values

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm trying to transform between points in different coordinate coordinate spaces (cartesian, relative to page, and polar).  I have classes for all of these and I'm trying to convert them by passing them into each other in the constructors.  I'm coming across an issue where the actual coordinate fields get lost.

```
class CartesianPoint {
    constructor(a, b) {
        if (a instanceof PagePoint) {
            this.SetFromPage(a);
        }
        else if (a instanceof PolarPoint) {
            this.SetFromPolar(a);
        }
        else {
            this.x = a;
            this.y = b;
        }
        this.SetFromPage = this.SetFromPage.bind(this);
        this.SetFromPolar = this.SetFromPolar.bind(this);
    }

    SetFromPage(pt) {
        this.x = pt.left;
        this.y = -pt.top;
    }

    SetFromPolar(pt) {
        this.x = pt.radius * Math.cos(pt.angle);
        this.y = pt.radius * Math.sin(pt.angle);
    }
}

class PagePoint {
    constructor(a, b) {
        if (a instanceof PolarPoint) {
            this.SetFromPolar(a);
        }
        else if (a instanceof CartesianPoint) {
            this.SetFromCartesian(a);
        }
        else {
            this.left = a;
            this.top = b;
        }
        this.SetFromPolar = this.SetFromPolar.bind(this);
        this.SetFromCartesian = this.SetFromCartesian.bind(this);
    }

    SetFromPolar(pt) {
        let cart = new CartesianPoint(pt);
        this.SetFromCartesian(cart);
    }

    SetFromCartesian(pt) {
        this.left = pt.x * 1;
        this.top = -pt.y * 1;
    }
}
```

The issue arises when I try to convert in a jQuery-ui draggable.start callback.

```
let pt1 = new CartesianPoint(new PagePoint(ui.position.left, ui.position.top)); // this does not work
let pt2 = new CartesianPoint(ui.position.left, -ui.position.top); // this works
let pt3 = new CartesianPoint(new PagePoint(1, 2)); // this works
```

Here is what I see in the Chrome inspector if I log pt1:

[image]

pt2 looks exactly as I would expect:

[image]

If you call pt1.x and pt1.y right after setting them in SetFromPage(), they have the correct values filled in, but they return NaN when called later from a different scope.

Comment: I do not see where `PagePoint()` returns anything. So `CartesianPoint()` would have a `null`  or `[Object]` parameter. It should work with the new Object. Do you see any Errors in the Console?

Comment: Nope, no errors.  I've now tried rewriting everything using a factory function and it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about why this happened, but I fixed it by rewriting these classes as so:

```
function CartesianPoint(a, b) {
    if (a.PointType === PointType.Page) {
        return CartesianPoint(a.left, -a.top);
    }
    else if (a.PointType === PointType.Polar) {
        return CartesianPoint(a.radius * Math.cos(a.angle), a.radius * Math.sin(a.angle));
    }
    else {
        let pt = {
            x: a,
            y: b,
            PointType: PointType.Cartesian
        };
        Object.freeze(pt); //this line appears to be what fixed it
        return pt;
    }
}
```

This would imply that it was losing the scope of this somewhere along the way.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze